# Images not loading from different website in Safari HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I made website where are only pictures in it and I'm displaying those images in my "main" website. In chrome, it works fine but in safari the aren't showing up at all. Even `createElement` for `div` isn't working. The problem is [this](https://infosyouneed.netlify.app/memegallery) link. Here's my code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  Draw_Images(i);
}

function Draw_Images(i) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = "meme" + i;
  div.style.borderRadius = "1%";
  div.style.width = "200px";
  div.style.height = "200px";
  div.style.border = "1px solid";
  div.style.padding = "0";
  div.style.margin = "0";
  var divParent = document.getElementById("memes_container").appendChild(div);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://iynmemes.netlify.app/images_memes/meme" + i + ".jpg";
  img.id = "image_meme" + i;
  img.style.width = "100%";
  img.style.height = "100%";
  img.style.objectFit = "contain";
  img.className = "img-fluid";
  img.alt = i;
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  divParent.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div id="memes_container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet (and shortened the number of images)

Comment: Works for me in Safari 15.5 (17613.2.7.1.8)

Comment: But why not use CSS and give them a class. That will cut down on the stuff you need to add to them

Comment: Try using [this](https://infosyouneed.netlify.app/memegallery) link.

Comment: you have a console error. navigator does not have [userAgentData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData) in most browsers. Remove or modify that statement

Comment: Fixed that but still didn't work

Comment: Yes it does. Clear your cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So removing some stuff worked for me. Basically Safari doesn't support `navigator.userAgentData` so it wasn't displaying images for that reason. So i had to remove it:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  Draw_Images(i);
}

function Draw_Images(i) {
  const isMobile = navigator.userAgentData.mobile;   //REMOVED THIS AND IT WORKED!!
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = "meme" + i;
  div.style.borderRadius = "1%";
  div.style.width = "200px";
  div.style.height = "200px";
  div.style.border = "1px solid";
  div.style.padding = "0";
  div.style.margin = "0";
  var divParent = document.getElementById("memes_container").appendChild(div);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://iynmemes.netlify.app/images_memes/meme" + i + ".jpg";
  img.id = "image_meme" + i;
  img.style.width = "100%";
  img.style.height = "100%";
  img.style.objectFit = "contain";
  img.className = "img-fluid";
  img.alt = i;
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  divParent.appendChild(img);
}
```